# Django Module, App and Import Question - object has no attribute 'form'

Tags: python, django

I have a signup form that needs to be loaded for every page of my site if the user is a guest.  I figured the easiest way to do this would be to create a "signup" app/module and have the form variable defined in the **init**.py so it was automatically initiated on every view, assuming I imported the module.  However, I'm having a bit of trouble getting my view to find the form variable.  "global name 'form' is not defined"  Below is my setup:

I have a /signup/**init**.py and /signup/form.py files.

This is my **init**.py

```
from django import forms
from signup.form import SignUpForm

form = SignupForm()
```

This is my form.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    fullname = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=25, initial='name', error_messages={'required': 'A unique username is required.', 'min_length': 'Your username must contain at least 3 characters.'})
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=25, initial='choose a username', error_messages={'required': 'A unique username is required.', 'min_length': 'Your username must contain at least 3 characters.'})
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=7, initial='choose a password', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a password.','min_length': 'Your password must contain at least 7 characters.'})
    email = forms.EmailField(initial='e-mail address', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a valid email address.', 'invalid': 'Please enter a valid email address.'})
    find_me = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)
    tos = forms.BooleanField(error_messages={'required': 'You must accept our Terms of Service.'})
```

And I'm trying to load those from my /views/index.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pymongo import *
from user import *
import mongo
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
import signup

#index view
def index(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form': signup.form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )
```

I removed the irrelevant code in index.py... but basically.. (i'll probably have an if else for the return statement to only return the 'form':form when the user is unregistered)

Am I approaching this completely wrong?  Anyone mind showing me what I'm doing incorrectly?

::Edit::

Also, I noticed that I didn't have signup.form in the return, but that still throws a

```
AttributeError at /
'module' object has no attribute 'form'
```

error.  I changed the code above to accommodate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just point out that the way you're doing it is an extremely bad idea. You have one instance of the form across every request: that's always going to be dangerous, allowing the possibility of information leakage across requests. Don't do it.

Instead, use the built-in mechanism that Django has to do this for you: [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). In your signup/form.py, define a simple function:

```
def signup_form(request):
    return SignupForm()
```

and add this to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py:

```
'signup.form.signup_form',
```

Comment: thank you very much.  Im a Django/Python newb.. I was completely unaware you could do that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `from signup import form` or `from signup import *` to make `form` variable available in your views.py. If you do `import signup` it will import the module with the namespace `signup` and to address the form you need to do `signup.form`.

Comment: yeah I jsut realized that after i posted this.. and I tried signup.form and it's giving me AttributeError at /
'module' object has no attribute 'form'

Comment: another problem could be that you have an overlapping name for `form`. Because first of all you see to have a form.py inside signup (`signup.form`). After that you "overwrite" this form variable via `form = SignupForm()` in your __init__.py. So you are using the same name for different things. Most likely that's why the second traceback comes from. It simply can't resolve `form` correctly.

Comment: Try to rename one of your `form` variables (either the `signup.form` module or you `form` reference in __init__.py). Then see if you still have this problem.

Comment: changed the variable to regform and it's still not working.  I'm doing the same exact thing for my mongo module and that works, so I have no idea why this is acting up.  The only difference between that and this, is that I'm calling additional objects on top of it.

Comment: this is what I'm calling in my view `user = mongo.db.users.find({'alias': 'chris'})` and this in my mongo module `from pymongo.connection import Connection

db = Connection("ip-here,ip-here,ip-here").spring`  so I'm not seeing what could possibly make the signup module not work

Comment: It sounds weird, but could it be that you have two `signup` modules in your python path. Could you check somehow if you import the right module (for example with `print os.path.dirname(signup.__file__)` in your view in `index.py`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do by assigning it to an identifier?

I would do this:

```
#init.py:
from django import forms
from signup.form import SignUpForm

#index view
def index(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form': signup.SignUpForm()},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )
```

OR

```
#init.py:
from django import forms
from signup.form import SignUpForm as Form

#index view
def index(request):

    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form': signup.Form()},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )
```

**UPDATE**

Change your form.py to :

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
```

instead of :

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
```

Comment: Something sketchy is going on with that... I get "No module named form" while trying to import anything within signup.  I even tried adding signup to the installed_apps in settings.py with the same result.

Comment: you need to have it in your installed apps. My guess is you have **forms** .py and you are trying to import signup. **form**.  Also i noticed your class is **SignupForm** and you are trying to import **SignUpForm**

Comment: I corrected the capitalization issue earlier.. and it is indeed called form.py and not forms.py

Comment: the "No module named form" error would suggest you have `import SignUpForm as form` not `import SignUpForm as Form` **OR** you have your `form = SignUpForm()` still in your file?